# Jhipster repository to load bag relationships

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jhipster

I was playing with Jhipster and once I got `BagRelationships` classes generated for me. I am not sure what caused it and what option should I use in CLI or JDL to generate those again. I tried to search for that but I found nothing unfortunately. Can anyone tell me about this option and how can I enable/disable it for a certain entity in Jhipster?